# How to give only one user more authorization than other users?

Tags: php

I have a question about giving authorization to a user by Admin but not to all users.

Example: Let assume we have 3 levels of users:
1) Admin  as genera manager 
2) HR , Sales  as department head 
3) users as normal employees

let say the Admin wants to go for a vacation for one week and wants to give HR department head an authorization(s) during the vacation but not Sales department head.

I DONT know if there is a key word in PHP for this scenario.

In my idea I want to make a php page in Admin account that shows all employees  and each employee has a button to go to next page to show all authorization that the Admin can do it and in each one has check box. If any check box is selected, the auth. will be shown in that user.

I hope this is help.

Thank you

Comment: you would need to set up a colum `rights` in your table `users` (0 = admin / 1 = HR / 2 = user). Then, a separate table, with all possible tasks people can do, each task having a role (ie: task1 -> 0 /  task2 -> 0 /  task3 -> 1). Then, when people log in, you can search which tasks they're authorized dealing with. That would also help you assigning tasks for when 'admin' is on leave -> small script with all tasks + checkboxes -> assign tasks to under-leveled user

Answer (score 0):

i think you should add a field in your user_tbl `role`int and its value will be 0 for user 1 for manager and 2 for Admin
when any user login then you have to check the role of the user and on its behalf (like if user A is login and its `role` is 2 then )  you can show admin features for him...

Comment: thank you for you response. However, what I mean is I want to give only one or two authorization of an admin to another user. For example, I I want HR head admin ONLY to be given authorization to increase salary and to add bonus.  I want the Admin to enter to HR information from the web page and check box for these two auths only